# Cannot resolve symbil intent - Did import intent

Tags: java, android, android-studio, compiler-errors

So trying to create a what I assume is a basic resumé app.
I got two classes, both have the same problem. It says it "cannot resolve symbol intent"

Did the google part but nothing makes sense..

Here's my code.

MainActivity class:

```
package com.example.boo.mittcv;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }



public void startActivity (View View){
intent i = new intent (MainActivity.this, Cv.class);
startActivity(i);


}
```

Cv Class:

```
package com.example.boo.mittcv;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;



public class Cv extends AppCompatActivity {



@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle SavedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.cvlook);
}
public void backToMain (View view){

    intent i = new intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capitalize the "I". It should be Intent, not intent :)

Comment: Its ironic sometimes... Thank you :)

Comment: No worries, happens more often than you think!